# Limit rectangle to parent area WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm doing an app that have a crop functionality, this crop use a rectangle that the user can drag the rectangle to a different position, the problem here is when I move the mouse outside the parent area the rectangle hides behind the parent area, like this image:[image]
(The read area painted is the missing area that is hidden behind the parent control).

My question is:

How I can restrict the move of the rectangle when the rectangle goes to the border of the parent? (the parent is a border control)

Thank you,

Comment: Can't you bind the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` to the parent control? Sorry, I'm just guessing - Maybe with some code I can try something.

Comment: @Tico I tried that, the problem here is that the rectangle is scaled because the image is zoomed, one thing that I forgot mention, the image contains a scroll viewer, so the level is Border->scroll Viewer->Image